# Get premise/building name from latitude and longitude in google maps jquery/javascript

Tags: google-maps, reverse-geocoding

Here is the detailed document for getting the formatted address,[google maps link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro).

But this returns only street_number,route,locality,country Example:7 Al Muraqqabat St - Dubai - United Arab Emirates. [Here is the link to get this](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=25.2679425,%2055.3219123999999743&sensor=true) and also this can be achieved with reverse coding.

But I was trying to find the premises/building name also for this.

Example: "Dream Palace hotel 7 Al Muraqqabat St - Dubai - United Arab Emirates

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two options to get a place name.

First one is using Places nearby search. You can request a list of places close to your coordinate `25.2679425,55.3219123999999743` ordered by distance from this point:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=25.2679425%2C55.3219123999999743&rankby=distance&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

The first item in the response of this request is 'Dream Palace Hotel'. You will see the name of the place in JSON name field.

Second option is using a Find place request based on the output from the reverse geocoding. Reverse geocoding gives you a formatted address and you know coordinate. So, use the following find place request to get name

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=7%20Al%20Muraqqabat%20St%20-%20Dubai%20-%20United%20Arab%20Emirates&inputtype=textquery&fields=name&locationbias=point%3A25.2679425%2C55.3219123999999743&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

This request returns

```
{
    "candidates":[
        {
            "name":"Dream Palace Hotel"
        }
    ],
    "debug_log":{
        "line":[

        ]
    },
    "status":"OK"
}
```

For further details please check Places API documentation:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#FindPlaceRequests

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think the one which you have shared is paid version of the maps, are there any ways to get with free version as well.

Comment: There is no Premium and Standard versions anymore. Google migrated to [Google Maps Platform](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/) with new pricing plan and free $200 limit per month. All APIs I mentioned are available in Maps Platform for all users.